# what should be the module name while adding menu in adminhtml

Tags: module, admin, magento-1, adminmenu

I've created a module which I named it in [**CamelCase**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CamelCase) like `MyCustomModule`. I've just started it as a little application and wanted to add a menu in `admin` for that the `adminhtml.xml` code is

```
<menu>
    <sales>
        <children>
            <my_custom_module>
                <title>My Custom Module</title>
                <sort_order>0</sort_order>
                <action>my_custom_module/adminhtml_order</action>
            </my_custom_module>
        </children>
    </sales>
</menu>
```

This is working fine. But as I see in other `xml`s they have an attribute `module` maybe for translation purpose like

```
<my_custom_module module="[module_name]">
    <title>My Custom Module</title>
    <sort_order>0</sort_order>
    <action>my_custom_module/adminhtml_order</action>
</my_custom_module>
```

for this I've replaced `[module_name]` with `my_custom_module`, `myCustomModule`, `mycustommodule` and `Company_MyCustomModule` but none of them work, even the page stops loading due to error. so my question is what could be the possible `[module_name]` to be passed here?

In case you may be asking for it

```
<admin>
    <routers>
        <my_custom_module>
            <use>admin</use>
            <args>
                <module>Company_MyCustomModule</module>
                <frontName>my_custom_module</frontName>
            </args>
        </my_custom_module>
    </routers>
</admin>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The name that is used in the node attribute `module` should normally be lower case and will match the the helper definition in the config.xml. If you set this wrong the error that you will get will be that it cannot find the helper.

```
<global>
    <helpers>
        <your_custom>
            <class>Your_Custom_Helper</class>
        </your_custom>
    </helpers>
</global>
```

This will mean that your code should be updated to:

```
<my_custom_module module="your_custom">
    <title>My Custom Module</title>
    <sort_order>0</sort_order>
    <action>my_custom_module/adminhtml_order</action>
</my_custom_module>
```

A good tutorial on adding menu items can be found at [codegento](http://codegento.com/2011/02/adding-a-new-admin-menu-item/)

Comment: Thanks for your answer... It was confusing because of the attribute name (`module`). It supposed to be `helper` to make some sense. Isn't it?